# jquery Ajax post to get pdf file not working checked with firebug no post occuring

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, pdf, post

I want to send ajax post request to  jsp page which on recieving the parameter  embeds para in it and sends back the pdf which i intend to display in the div Upon checking with firebug i noticied no ajax post are occurring.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#click").click(function() 
        {
        name = $("#name").val();
            age = $("#age").val();
            $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",                              
                url : "Test.jsp",                                         
                    data : "name=" + name + "&age=" + age,                                  
                    success : function(data) {                                              
                    $("#pdf").html(data);                                                 
                    } });                                                                            

                   });
                   });
         </script>
         </head>
         <body>

         <input type="text" id="name" name="name" >
         <br />
    <br /> Age :
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age">
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="click">Click Me</button>
    <div id="pdfenter code here"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied your code into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaLEd/), and it shows it making the ajax request in firebug. Can you try the jsfiddle and see if you see the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass your data like this :

```
data : {'name': name, 'age': age},
```

**EDIT :**

also close your script tag :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >
----------------------------------------------------------------------- here -^
```

become :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" />
```

Comment: Still no tried it no change onlick no post is occuring checked using firebug anyway thanks for trying